# Error implementing custom system call in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel, system-calls

I mainly followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AP-tBd84vbM) tutorial but got an error.

Here's what I did:

cd linux-5.16.15

mkdir helloworld

cd helloworld

gedit **helloworld.c**

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>

asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void){
    printk(“Hello World\n”);
    return 0;
}
```

gedit **Makefile**

```
obj-y := helloworld.o
```

cd ..

gedit **Makefile**

find second core-y and add

`helloworld/` to that line

cd include/linux

gedit **syscalls.h**

in the end of the syscalls.h file before #endif add,
`asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void);`

cd ../..

cd arch/x86/entry/syscalls

gedit **syscall_64.tbl**

```
450 64 helloworld  sys_helloworld
```

When I ran the make command, I got this error:

```
ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xe10): undefined reference to `__x64_sys_helloworld'
make: *** [Makefile:1161: vmlinux] Error 1
```

I tried changing the sys_helloworld to __x64_sys_helloworld in the syscalls.h file and the syscall_64.tbl file but that led to this error:

```
ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.o:(.rodata+0xe10): undefined reference to `__x64___x64_sys_helloworld'
ld: arch/x86/entry/syscall_x32.o:(.rodata+0xe10): undefined reference to `__x64___x64_sys_helloworld'
make: *** [Makefile:1161: vmlinux] Error 1
```

What did I do wrong? Can someone please help me out?

Edit:
I got that part. Just changed helloworld.c to this:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>

//asmlinkage long sys_helloworld(void){
SYSCALL_DEFINE0(helloworld)
{

    printk("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But now when I run `make modules_install install` I get this error:

```
arch/x86/Makefile:142: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
ln: target '/source' is not a directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1477: __modinst_pre] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:350: __build_one_by_one] Error 2
```

What's wrong now? Please help.

Comment: The `ln` error is coming from [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v5.16/Makefile#L1477). It's unclear why your `$(MODLIB)` is the empty string. Did you change it? Related, but possibly irrelevant: you have a file called `source` in your root directory.